# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str' when creating n-gram

Tags: python, attributeerror

1.I want to apply n-grams on my data set. I created the code and want to test on my data set:

```
def generate_N_grams(text,ngram=1):
  words=[word for word in text.split(" ").str if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]  
  
  temp=zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(0,ngram)])
  ans=[' '.join(ngram) for ngram in temp]
  return ans
news['text_process_1gram'] = news['text_process'].str.split(',')
news['text_process_1gram'] = news['text_process'].astype(str)
news['text_process_1gram'] = news['text_process'].apply(lambda x:generate_N_grams(x, 1))
```

2.And then I got the error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'. Why did I get this information?

Comment: str(text.split(" "))

Answer (score 1):

```py
example = ['1', '2', '3']
print(example.str)
```

This will result in `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'` because a list has no attribute `str`.

---

```py
words = [word for word in text.split(',') if word != 'whatever']
```

`text.split(" ")` will result in a list of strings, you don't have to ensure that `word` is a string.

Comment: thanks! now the code is running without any errors